# Form with recaptcha redirect after submission

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, recaptcha

I'm trying to learn express/nodejs and implement a form, where after recaptcha you can click and download a file. But after form submission I'm being redirected to localhost/submit with only status code on the page. This is driving me crazy, I just want to enable download button after passing recaptcha. I believe this is obvious, but not for me.

server.js file

```
// Load Node modules
var express = require("express");
const fetch = require("isomorphic-fetch");
// Initialise Express
var app = express();
// Render static files
app.use(express.static("public"));
// Port website will run on
app.listen(8080);
// To accept HTML form data
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
// Here, HTML form is submit
app.post("/submit", (req, res) => {
  const name = req.body.name;
  // getting site key from client side
  const response_key = req.body["g-recaptcha-response"];
  // Put secret key here, which we get from google console
  const secret_key = "6LdGoQohAAAAAJe6wa_-xayew_ht3N6Lm-kSdbW9";
  console.log(res);

  // Hitting POST request to the URL, Google will
  // respond with success or error scenario.
  const url = `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=${secret_key}&response=${response_key}`;

  // Making POST request to verify captcha
  fetch(url, {
    method: "post",
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((google_response) => {
      // google_response is the object return by
      // google as a response
      if (google_response.success == true) {
        //   if captcha is verified
        return res.sendStatus(200);
      } else {
        // if captcha is not verified
        console.log(google_response);

        return res.sendStatus(400);
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // Some error while verify captcha
      return res.json({ error });
    });
});
```

html form

```
<form class="main-form" action="/submit" method="post" id="myForm">
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-element">
            <label for="form-delivery">Номер поставки:</label>
            <input type="text" name="delivery" required id="form-delivery" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-element">
            <label for="form-num">Номер ТТН:</label>
            <input type="text" name="delivery2" id="form-num" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-element">
            <label for="form-date" req>Дата формирования:</label>
            <input type="date" name="delivery3" id="form-date" required />
          </div>
          <div class="form-element">
            <label for="form-client">Клиент:</label>
            <input type="text" name="delivery4" id="form-client" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-element">
            <label for="form-car">Гос. номер:</label>
            <input type="text" name="delivery5" id="form-car" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-element">
            <label for="form-cert">Номер сертификата:</label>
            <input type="text" name="delivery6" id="form-cert" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="g"></div>
        <button class="download-link" type="submit">Скачать</button>
      </form>
```

Comment: First, you should not share secret keys on StackOverflow. Then, I miss the code where you process the `delivery`, ..., `delivery6` fields of your form. You only verify the recaptcha and respond with 200 OK if that succeeds.

Comment: @Heiko Theißen
 These keys are for testing only, thanks for noticing anyway. I process these fields on client side with js, but the main problenm is that respond 200 - why am I being redirect to localhost/submit with this status code on the screen and nothing else? Ideally, i would love to send this code back to client and do the rest on client side

Comment: Submitting the form navigates (not: redirects) to `http://localhost/submit` because the `<form action="/submit">` says so. What purpose does the recaptcha protection serve if you don't want to do any processing on your server? What do you want to protect?

Comment: @Heiko Theißen
I was thinking about database with files and that bots or spam could overwhelm the system or something like, idk really. I just saw that some big websites have recaptcha protection before allowing users to download anything, isn't that true?

Comment: Yes, but after passing the recaptcha, these websites then do something on their server (or their database) _within the same request_. You don't do anything after passing the recaptcha.

Comment: @Heiko Theißen Thats what I'm currently trying to implement, I want to send the result of recaptcha to client, evaluate it there, and if it's passed allow to download the file. But I am stuck at the part of sending the result back to client, all I get is navigation to ```http://localhost/submit``` with this code on the screen

Comment: If you send the recaptcha result to the client, it could be manipulated by a malicious user, so the protection could be circumvented. Anyway, if you want to send something back to the client, use [`res.send`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.send), not just `res.sendStatus`.

Comment: @Heiko Theißen so, possible solution might be to move all the logic from client side to server side?

Comment: That's a good idea.

Comment: @Heiko Theißen alright, thanks a lot